# Error while using getline() in c++

Tags: c++

I am using getline to read strings and print but while using that I am unable to give input so I used ignore()

**Code**

```
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  string str;
  for(int i=0;i<t;i++)     
      {     cin.ignore();
            getline (cin, str);//reading string
           cout  << str << endl;
      }
  return 0;
```

When using that while printing output every first character from second line of output are missing?

Comment: What `Error` do you get, could you post the error text?

Answer (score 3):

The [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function *reads* (but doesn't store) the newline, so in the second (and every following) iteration of the loop your call to `ignore` will read the first character of that line.

You should move the `ignore` call to before the loop.

Comment: it worked can u please explain me aloberately about getline()

Comment: @AravindPabbisetty No, but if you follow the link you will find a pretty detailed reference.